# Looping async functions in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, web-scraping, puppeteer

so here's my problem. In the following function I want to get some data from a website using puppeteerjs. The function searches for a product on the website with the names its getting from a mongodb database. So here is my question. I want to loop the function through an array of names I'm getting from mongo. So if the function is completed once , it starts again with the next name in the array until there is nothing else in the array.

```
async function scrape() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36');
    await page.goto(dealer);
    await page.type('.Search-bar-text-input', arrayOfArticles[i]);
    await page.click('.Embedded-search-button')
    await page.waitFor('.BuyingOptions-total-price');

    const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
        let path = '.BuyingOptions-total-price';
        let price = document.querySelector(path).innerText;

        return price;
    });

}
```

So I originally wanted to simply do that with this:

```
for (var i = 0, len = arrayOfArticles.length; i < len; i++){
```

but from what I've read that doesnt work with async functions. How would I archive the same for my function?

Comment: `that doesnt work with async functions` Sure it just, just `await` each call of `scrape`

Comment: I already tried that and it still didnt work, how exactly would you code that?

Comment: `(async () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfArticles.length; i++) await scrape();
})();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can go with a slight modification

```
return page.evaluate(() => {
    let path = '.BuyingOptions-total-price';
    let price = document.querySelector(path).innerText;

    return price;
});

//----------------

(async () => {
    for (var i = 0, len = arrayOfArticles.length; i < len; i++){
        const result = await scrape(arrayOfArticles[i]);
    }
})()
```

Comment: so I found the problem , there was something wrong with the database, the code you provided worked like a charm, thank you very much